# How to search a used extension id in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to search an extension id which is used inside a plug-in. Is there any shortcut for that? Like for searching the plug-ins we have following shortcut: CTRL+SHIFT+A, so similarly can we search the used extension ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and see if the [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) gives you the identifiers you need:
(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

[image: eclipse plugin Spy]

Note, as [explained here](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/06/22/eclipse-plug-in-spy-eclipse-rcp/) (if you want the id from an RCP application):

> To use the the Eclipse Plug-in Spy in your Eclipse RCP application include the plug-in **`org.eclipse.pde.runtime`** into your application.